# AS3 drawing Sprite on BitmapData memory leak

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory-leaks, air

I have an AIR app that renders images from a Flash editor. You can customize several surfaces - they all have the same width and height. Each surface is then rendered by the AIR app.

I'm struggling with a memory leak I fail to address.

For each surface I need to render, I have a Sprite containing many components (other sprites - some having event listeners, BitmapDatas and other children components, sprites, etc).

I'm already aware of BitmapData issues to be garbage collected, I tested both :

- creating a new BitmapData for each rendering then dispose() and point to null
- reuse a single BitmapData for each rendering

Memory leak is still happening in equal proportion.

Here is my loop :

```
var bm:BitmapData = new BitmapData(destDim.x, destDim.y, true, bgColor);
var mtx:Matrix = new Matrix();
trace('before drawing :'+(System.privateMemory/1024));
bm.draw(myBigSprite, mtx, null, null, null, true);
trace('after drawing :'+(System.privateMemory/1024));
var result:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bm, PixelSnapping.NEVER, true);

//return result and encode Bitmap to png

result.bitmapData.dispose();
result.bitmapData = null;
result = null;
```

Result :

```
before drawing :208364
after drawing :302816
Wrote bitmap to file: surface0.png
before drawing :303296 
after drawing :446160 
Wrote bitmap to file: surface1.png 
before drawing :446160
after drawing :565212
Wrote bitmap to file: surface2.png 
before drawing :565924
after drawing :703100 
Wrote bitmap to file: surface3.png 
before drawing :703572
after drawing :834420 
Wrote bitmap to file: surface4.png
```

I feel like I'm missing something in draw function behaviour. It seems like I have newly created instances of the components of myBigSprite that persists after draw operation.

I tried to completely destroy myBigSprite at the end of each loop, it does not change anything....

Any hint would be appreciated !

Comment: how do you know the garbage collection process ran? do you force it? also just as a sidenote, forcing gc by calling System.gc() only works in debug player as far as i know.

Comment: As you can see the memory between the end of a draw operation and the beginning of the next one is almost equivalent, but there is a lot of memory consuming operations in between. Especially encoding bitmap to png. So I assume GC process is doing its job as all the resource I wanted to be cleaned are cleaned except for the draw function. I never explicitly call System.gc().

Comment: do you set your "result" to null, since it holds a reference to the bitmapdata?

Comment: Yes I do, I edited my snippet as it was not clear, sorry.

Comment: @Bedu33 Normally, Garbage Collector is lazy and will not dispose of any unused memory as soon as it is unused. So I **advise** you to try calling **System.gc()** explicitly and see the memory measurements. If doing so will resolve your problem, then it is not a memory leak, it is just GC being lazy.

Comment: I agree with others that you have to confirm garbage collection. I looked into it when I first did this bitmap stuff and I was surprised at how long garbage collection can take.

Comment: I confirm garbage collection does not have any effect on this memory issue. It collects anything but the amount of memory generated by the draw operation.
Even if I strip any other operation (encoding, etc) and I put System.gc() at the end of each loop (twice because I read somewhere it could be helpful), nothing is collected.

Comment: I would suggest showing all your code related to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, I eventually understood and fixed this issue.

First of all, I installed and ran Adobe Scout. Excellent tool.

[image: Adobe Scout memory profiling]

As you may not see (plus it's in French language), I generated 3 surfaces corresponding to the edges. The "big" green bar on the right which is mass memory consuming represent "Bitmap display objects". Interesting ! Never heard of those before.

A Google search later, I found this article : https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e26.html

It explains

> For example, in the code excerpt shown earlier, once the load
>   operation for the pict Loader object is complete, the pict object will
>   have one child display object, which is the bitmap, loaded. To access
>   this bitmap display object, you can write pict.getChildAt(0).

So I began to undestand that, somehow, maybe Bitmap object are attached as children on some objects of `myBigSprite`.

Finally, I created a recursive function to search and destroy all `Bitmap`, `BitmapData` and `ByteArray` objects contained in `myBigSprite` AFTER the `draw` operation

```
//inside render function
bm.draw(myBigSprite, mtx, null, null, null, true);
destroyDisplayObjects(myBigSprite);
```

...

```
private function destroyDisplayObjects(obj):void{
    if ("numChildren" in obj){
        for (var i:int = 0; i<obj.numChildren; i++)
        {
            destroyDisplayObjects(obj.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
    else {
        if (flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(obj) == "flash.display::Bitmap"){
            //trace ('FREE BITMAP');
            obj.bitmapData.dispose();
            obj.bitmapData = null;
            obj = null;
            return;
        }
        else if (flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(obj) == "flash.display::BitmapData"){
            //trace ('FREE BITMAPDATA');
            obj.dispose();
            obj = null;
            return;
        }
        else if (flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(obj) == "flash.display::ByteArray"){
            //trace ('FREE BYTEARRAY');
            obj.clear();
            obj = null;
            return;
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Et voilà, memory is 100% cleaned after the draw operation, no more leak :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare you `Bitmap` and `BitmapData` outside of any functions and then simply recycle them for usage inside of your loop (instead of creating a `new` anything to be added in memory).

Use `.dispose()` only on the last image when you're sure you don't need bitmap data from `bm` variable anymore. Otherwse, if disposed, you'll have to create a new alternative `var someThing :BitmapData = new BitmapData` again for further usage.

```
////# declare globally (not inside some specific function..)

//var destDim :Point = new Point(your_X_num , your_Y_num);
//var bgColor :uint = 0x505050;

var bm:BitmapData = new BitmapData(destDim.x, destDim.y, true, bgColor);
var result:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bm, PixelSnapping.NEVER, true);
//result.bitmapData = bm; //can be set here but done within function for clarity...

var mtx:Matrix = new Matrix();


////# update bitmap by replacing its bitmapdata with new colour values of existing pixels

function Here_is_my_loop (): void 
{
    trace('before drawing :'+(System.privateMemory/1024));

    //overwrite pixel colours in bitmap (result)
    bm.draw(myBigSprite, mtx, null, null, null, true);
    result.bitmapData = bm; //update bitmap

    trace('after drawing :'+(System.privateMemory/1024));


    //return result and encode Bitmap to png

    //result.bitmapData.dispose();
    //result.bitmapData = null;
    //result = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, as I said in my original post, I have the exact same result with a reused BitmapData.
However I tried one more time with your solution, and I confirm it has the same result.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how I missed _"reuse a single BitmapData for each rendering"_ last time but, using `new` in a loop is a good way to eat memory. My code should just be **overwriting** already existing data so can't understand how that somehow **adds** more new data (increases memory usage size). I'll investigate when possible to jump on Flash.

Comment: "My code should just be overwriting already existing data so can't understand how that somehow adds more new data (increases memory usage size)"
This is exactly my question also :)